# Accessing a Bluetooth "ConnectedThread" from various activities

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, handler

I have created a BluetoothManager much like the one in [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=MDP-Group-10-master/AeroDragon/src/com/mdp/aero/BluetoothManager.java) example.  This object is instantiated in a connection activity, reached from the main acitivty by clicking on a "Connect" button, which provides a ListView of selectable devices.  Works great so far.

I am now connected and have a BluetoothManager.ConnectedThread running and the streams set up.  I would now like to be able to send Bluetooth data from/to various other activities when they are running.  For example, I will want to chart realtime values when the charting activity is running.

As far as I can tell, the pushing of the data out from the ConnectedThread will occur via a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), which is a new topic for me.  What I am unclear on his how other activities might access the ConnectedThread's write() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, even though a singleton could be a solution, android `Service`'s are there for this purpose, since these are elements that can keep running when your UI is out. So my suggestion would be to create a sticky service an then you have two options:

- Handle data using a handler between the activity and the `Service`. Maybe if you are not too familiar with the `Handler` api this will take some time to you. In [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) example of the official documentation you can also check how to use the handler.
- Create a bound service, to which you can bind from the activities and send some data when required. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) you have the official information about bound services.

You can have a look to [this](http://androidsrc.net/android-loopers-and-handlers-code-tutorial/) tutorial to get more information about handlers.

Comment: Ok.  I will take a look at Services and get back to you.  I didn't think a Service was necessary in this case, given that the [Android Developers Example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)  used something very similar.

Comment: Well it depends on your needs, how long the connection will live and such. But I think it will be easier to handle that way from my experience.

Comment: Just wanted to come back and mark this as answered.  I spent some time studying Services and did get this running using the command pattern.  Thanks.