# NPE when attempting to invoke LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance().sendBroadcast()

Tags: android, multithreading, service

New to Android and developing an app that will deliver Bluetooth data to several different activities.  I have a ConnectActivity that performs discovery and presents the devices to the user and when the user selects a device, as suggested by someone in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475773/accessing-a-bluetooth-connectedthread-from-various-activities/39476313?noredirect=1#comment66272082_39476313) discussion, starts a BluetoothService.

BluetoothService extends Service and starts a background thread which will eventually be used to block on an InputStream, and broadcast data to activities when it is available (i.e. after those activities poll via startService()).

Here is the Activity.  Defines a receiver:

```
public class ConnectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    // My test receiver just to see if things are working.
    private BroadcastReceiver mDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(D)
            Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast received.");
    }
};
```

Starts the service onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    IntentFilter dataFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothService.INCOMING_DATA);
    registerReceiver(mDataReceiver, dataFilter);

    // Start the service with an intent identifying the context ("this" is an Activity,
    // which inherits from Context) and the recipient.
    Intent i = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
    i.putExtra(BluetoothService.COMMAND, "MY_COMMAND"); // Add the command as payload to the intent.
    if(D)
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting service.");
    startService(i);
}
```

And, finally, connect on a button press:

```
private void connect(){
   if(D)
        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to device " + (mBluetoothDevices.get(mSelectedPos).toString()) + " at position " + mSelectedPos);

    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Connecting");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.show();

    if(D)
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to connect.");
    mBluetoothService.connect(mBluetoothDevices.get(mSelectedPos), dialog);
```

Here is my service:

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {
...
    public void connect (BluetoothDevice device, ProgressDialog dialog){
    ....
    // Start the thread to connect to the device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, dialog, this);
    mConnectThread.start();
}
```

The ConnectThread connects successfully and starts a ConnectedThread which is intended to send data back to the acitvity as it comes in.  I am including all of it since this is where my issue is:

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final String mmMYNAME = "ConnectedThread";
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private final Context mmContext;


    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, Context context) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        mmContext = context;

        InputStream tryIn = null;
        OutputStream tryOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tryIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
            tryOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, mmMYNAME + " could not create streams.", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tryIn;
        mmOutStream = tryOut;
        mConnectedThreadEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(mmMYNAME);
        Intent i = new Intent(INCOMING_DATA);

        while(mConnectedThreadEnabled) {
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            if(D)
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread is running.");

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mmContext).sendBroadcast(i); //KABOOM
        }
        if(D)
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping ConnectedThread.");

    }

    public void cancel() {
        if(D)
            Log.d(TAG,"Canceling ConnectedThread.");

        try {
            if(D)
                Log.d(TAG,"Shutting down existing socket.");
            mConnectedThreadEnabled = false;
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that on the line:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mmContext).sendBroadcast(i); //KABOOM
```

I am receiving:

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:102)
                                                                                at com.company.me.app.BluetoothService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothService.java:255)*

I am not clear on what the issue is, given that debug indicates that mmContext and i both seem to be properly created.

Comment: Perhaps your service is being destroyed while your thread is running. Have `ConnectedThread` hold onto `context.getApplicationContext()` instead of `context`.

Comment: Well, the context does not appear to be null, according to the debugger.  Isn't the point of Service to stick around until explicitly stopped or reclaimed by the OS in emergency?  By the way, I was going to link to your book because I used it as an overview of Services.  :)   Great book.

Comment: "Isn't the point of Service to stick around until explicitly stopped or reclaimed by the OS in emergency?" -- a service started by `startService()` will run until `stopService()` / `stopSelf()`, or the service crashes, or the process is terminated. However, I don't know all of your code and so I do not know how long you are keeping this service around. Thanks for the kind words!

Comment: The service is is not stopped anywhere at this point.  I am passing the service Context above with the line  'mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, dialog, this);' ... through the ConnectThread to the ConnectedThread.  Are you suggesting that I should use 'this.getpplicationContext()' ?

Comment: Well, the `ContextWrapper` that is `mmContext` is wrapping a `null` `Context`, based on your error message. Usually, I see that when somebody creates a component via the constructor (e.g., `new BluetoothService()`) or tries using superclass methods from field initializers on a component. I don't see either of those things occurring here, though admittedly I don't have all of your code.

Comment: In this case `BluetoothService` _is_ created in `onCreate()` for the `ConnectActivity` that will use it and is assigned to a member.

Comment: In `onCreate()`, you are calling `startService()`, not `new BluetoothService()`. Calling `startService()` is fine; calling `new BluetoothService()` is not. It is possible that `BluetoothService` has fields with initializers (not shown in your listing), but that's not where you are crashing.

Comment: Didn't show it but the `mBluetoothService` referenced in `ConnectActivity` above is created in a helper to `OnCreate` which performs a `mBluetoothService = new BluetoothService();`.  I do think that you are onto something because I am seeing unexpected (at least to me) behavior with regard to initializations. For example I'm initializing the `mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();` in `BluetoothService`'s `onCreate` and later on it is null.  I also noticed the  address of `BluetoothService` is changing for a single execution.  Something fundamental I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which performs a mBluetoothService = new BluetoothService();

**Never** create instances of components yourself. Get rid of this line. Anything that has been using `mBluetoothService` needs to be rewritten to:

- be in the service itself, or
- use service binding (e.g., `bindService()`, with the activity then calling methods on the supplied `Binder`), or
- use some other pattern, to avoid the activity trying to have a direct reference to the service, let alone creating an instance of the service itself

Comment: Ok.  I had designed the service to only support a default "poll the Bluetooth device" through command pattern and a public method to start the initial connection.  I should support _all_ behavior through the command pattern (or binding) with no explicit instantiation of the service.  Many thanks.